# Formulation of SVM optimization problem

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, constraints

I need help in verifying/understanding a step in formulating an optimization problem used for support vector machines (though this question doesn't need any background in SVM). Consider a bunch of $m$ points $x_1, x_2,\ldots,x_m\in\mathbb{R}^n$, a vector $w\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and let
$$\gamma_i=\frac{\langle x_i,w\rangle}{\|w\|} + \frac{b}{\|w\|}$$

where $b=-c\|w\|$ and $c$ is a constant. For this question, assume that $\gamma_i$ is positive for all $i$. Define
$$\gamma\equiv \min_{i=1,\ldots,m} \gamma_i$$ and consider the optimization problem

$$\max_{w,b} \gamma
\\\text{subject to}\ \frac{\langle x_i,w\rangle}{\|w\|} + \frac{b}{\|w\|}\geq\gamma
$$

Letting $\hat \gamma=\gamma\|w\|$, the above can be rephrased as:

$$\max_{w,b} \frac{\hat\gamma}{\|w\|}
\\\text{subject to}\ \langle x_i,w\rangle + b\geq\hat\gamma
$$

Now we have $\hat\gamma=\min_i (\langle x_i,w\rangle + b)$ and assuming that $w'=w/\hat\gamma$ (which implies $b'=b/\hat\gamma$ since $w$ and $b$ are proportional), we see that  $\min_i (\langle x_i,w'\rangle + b')=1$. So we can finally rephrase the optimization problem as (**note that earlier we were maximizing w.r.t. $w, b$; now we're maximizing w.r.t. $w',b'$**)

$$\max_{w',b'} \frac{1}{\|w'\|}
\\\text{subject to}\ \langle x_i,w'\rangle + b'\geq 1
$$

Is this chain of reasoning correct or have I missed something/made an error in any step? Also, this problem is based on the [following lecture](http://cs229.stanford.edu/notes/cs229-notes3.pdf). The optimization problem is stated on **page 6** and the objective is $\max_{\gamma, w, b}\gamma$. Shouldn't it be $\max_{w,b}\gamma$, since we're only allowed to freely change $w$ and $b$?

Answer (score 2):

The idea of this proof is essentially correct, the confusion about the difference between maximizing over $\gamma, w, b$ and over $w, b$ seems to be because there are two different possible ways to formulating the problem: One where you define $\gamma = \min_i \gamma_i$, as you do above. The other way is to specify constraints where $\gamma \le \gamma_i$ for all $i$ and optimize over $\gamma$ (which is essentially equivalent since the optimal choice of $\gamma$ will be the minimum of the $\gamma_i$).

The optimization problem as you have written it is sort of redundant, since  $\frac{\langle x_i,w\rangle}{\|w\|} + \frac{b}{\|w\|} \ge \gamma$ is true just by your definition, and there is no need to write it out as a constraint. For it to be a linear program, technically you would have to do away with the definition that $\gamma = \min_i \gamma_i$, and just let $\gamma$ be a variable you optimize over.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply and thanks for the answer! Could you please elaborate on your first paragraph a bit more? The second paragraph makes complete sense. If you refer to this: http://cs229.stanford.edu/notes/cs229-notes3.pdf , then basically what I'm struggling to understand is the jump from the second last formulation (as in my question) with $\hat\gamma/\|w\|$ to the last formulation in which $\hat\gamma$ is replaced by $1$. This jump is described at the end of page 6 and the start of page 7 in the linked notes. If that makes sense to you, could you please explain that to me as well?

Comment: Pg.5 in the same notes lines 14-21 describes about scaling factor for $(w,b)$ s.t $\hat \gamma = 1$.The idea is since you deal with $\frac{w}{\|w\|}$ unit vector and such the $\gamma$ is really an invariant when you replace say $w$ with $3w$ etc. What it says you choose appropriate values of $w$ and $b$ such that $\hat \gamma = 1$